# Extract keyword from a table in doc file and write it into a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import win32com.client as w32c

import win32com.client as win32
word = win32.Dispatch("Word.Application")
word.Visible = 0
word.Documents.Open("MyDocument")
doc = word.ActiveDocument
```

I keep getting error:

> ImportError: No module named 'win32com'

Working with python 3.4.1 on windows 7

Apart from the error which can be removed by installing win32 package my primary question is :

In the table I have some N number of verification templates written in bold corresponding to a sequence number. So I have to read all the templates for that particular sequence number and write it into a different file. 
Please help as to how do we read a table in .doc file .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install python `win32` package.

You will get it from [`SourceForge`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) or [`other site`](http://starship.python.net/~skippy/win32/Downloads.html)

Comment: thanx @Lafada...i have edited my question....any idea about reading a table in .doc file...?

Comment: Sorry @Maxxie I never worked with win32 :(. But I know the error so I gave answer.

Comment: Ok...@Lafada...no problem... :)